# Porting my hibernate Dao layer in a stand-alone java app?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a spring mvc application that I am using Hibernate with. 
I am using the sessionFactory.getCurrentSession in my Dao methods (not hibernate support).

What I want to know is, what do I have to do to be able to use my hibernate database layer
in a non-web application?

**I have a stand-alone java application (that runs via main) where I load spring's application context 
programatically and then get my service layer (which depends on my hibernate db layer).
Do I need to do anything special in my spring.xml file to setup hibernate's session?**

In my spring mvc web app, I did annotate my Dao methods with the @Transactional annotation.
(I want the transaction on a per call basis, not for a group of db calls).

P.S In my web app, how are sessions created/destroyed, is it per request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get hold of the spring `ApplicationContext` from **main** method. it will behave exactly the same as the one in web.

```
ApplicationContext context = new  ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
YourDAO yDao = (YourDAO)context.getBean("yourDAO");
yDao.callYourSpecialMethod();
```

So, from this point there is no dependancy for hibernate, it should work automatically. here just the view gets changed, no logical or structural changes. So the transactions and other things should work as usual.

Comment: what if I wanted a session transaciton to last per request?

Comment: **request** is a bit confusing, basically every time your DAO method is called, one **session** is created and is closed after the use(assuming the transaction is at the DAO layer).